# coordinates of a subview with respect to superview of superview

Tags: ios, coordinates, subview

Given a viewController's view, self.view, and a subview referenced as self.Toolbar.contentView.rightButton, how to get the coordinates of rightButton in self.view's coordinate system?

Answer (score 1):

```
[self.view convertRect:self.Toolbar.contentView.rightButton.frame fromView:self.Toolbar.contentView]
```

Comment: Actually the value returned is incorrect when called from viewdidload.